# How can I continue developing on my Alexa Skill while it is in 'Certification'?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I just submitted a new version for certification and would like to start developing on my next version with new features.

But somehow - since my skill is in certification mode I can not start a new dev-version.

Is there a way to develop on a new version while it is in this long (4-7 days) certification mode?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently you can't modify a skill that is under certification, in general there are three statuses:

- **Development**: The skill is available only to you. If you have enabled it for testing, you can test it on devices registered to your developer account.
- **Certification**: Amazon is currently reviewing the skill for publication. During this time, ***you cannot edit*** the configuration.
- **Live**: The skill has been published and is available to users. You cannot edit the configuration for live skills. To start development on an updated version, make your changes on the development version instead.

Once your skill is published to end users (Live status), your skill’s status changes to live. You cannot change the configuration for a live skill. ***A new development version is automatically created in the developer portal***. This version has the same information as the original live version, you can use this new version to continue to work on your skill to improve it and add features.

Taken from the [Amazon Alexa documentation.](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/publishing-an-alexa-skill#publication-status)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what Lorena Salamanca advised in the case of the Skill status being Live, to access the new development version in the developer portal you must click the little Play-type arrow next to the Skill name - this reveals the development version neatly folded underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Jurik refers to the moment prior to the approval of the certification. At this point the best alternative is to generate a copy of your skill and rename it. If you work directly on the console you will not be able to edit your original skill.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).